# Attempting cifar-10 download via TF and get certicate error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am starting out in machine vision, and have tried to download CIFAR-10 direct via python code and keep being stopped by a certificate error.

Not being a python expert, am not sure how to work aorund this :

I excute the python code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
cifar10 = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10
```

and then if fails with this error :

```
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1422, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 274, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 82, in urlretrieve
    response = urlopen(url, data)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1076)>
```

I am not sure how to either download the dataset manually and get python to load from disk, or force it to ignore the error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Download with http instead of https

Comment: How do I force python to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you don't have the correct certificates installed, and the https query is failing to connect to the cifar-10 database.

You can bypass python and manually download it from: [cifar-10-python.tar.gz](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz). Then you will just need to point python to wherever you downloaded the file.

Or, if you are on a Mac then you can try installing the required certificates by running this file: `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command` and then running your script again

Alternatively,
Edit your local copy of this file [cifar-10.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/cifar10.py) and rerun your script.

```
# line 78
origin = 'https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz'

# and change it to be:
origin = 'http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz'
```

This file may exist in a few spots depending on how you installed tensorflow though.

Comment: OK, I am a beginner at python, so all I need to know is how to point to a copy of the the cifar10.tgz file and import it into keras please? e.g. c:\temp\cifar10.tgz   Other code i have seen is tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()  but not sure how to link the load_data() part and the .tgz file on disk. Thanks.

Comment: I literally included the exact code that is being used to do that: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/cifar10.py. Just set the `path = Path('c:\temp\cifar10.tgz')` and it will work.